# Query Output as tree MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

I have two tables in my MySQL database :

**Folder table**

```
+----+----------+
| ID |   Name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | folder 1 |
|  2 | folder 2 |
|  3 | folder 3 |
+----+----------+
```

And **File table**

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
| ID |  Name  | ID_folder |   Ref   |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | file1  |         2 | ref133  |
|  2 | file 2 |         3 | ref2044 |
|  3 | file 3 |         3 | refA001 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
```

I want create a MySQL query that output this result :

***Output:***

```
+---------+---------+
|  Name   |   Ref   |
+---------+---------+
| folder1 |         |
| folder2 |         |
| file1   | ref133  |
| folder3 |         |
| file2   | ref2044 |
| file3   | refA001 |
+---------+---------+
```

ie, display a folder first (father) and under each folder these files

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Union`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) and with three different values to order (the file number to list the file, the folder number to list the folders, and the `isFile` value to make the folder appears before its files), this query doing what you want:

```
SELECT Name, Ref
FROM
    ((SELECT Name, '' as Ref, 0 AS isFile, ID as ID_folder, ID
      FROM Table1)
     UNION
     (SELECT Name, Ref, 1 AS isFile, ID_folder, ID
      FROM Table2))
AS tmp
ORDER BY ID_folder, isFile, ID;
```